# SQL Server Full-Text Search not working on PDF File

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, fulltext-index, full-text-catalog

My full text search works with doc and docx but not working with pdf. The filters have pdf fullpath: C:\WINDOWS\system32\Windows.Data.Pdf.dll
version: 6.2.19041.1023
Tell me what could be the matter?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FilesSearch](
    [id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [rConclusionCard] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [rConclusionCardFile] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [FileAgreementContent] [varbinary](max) NOT NULL,
    [FileAgreementName] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [FileExt]  AS (lower(reverse(substring(reverse([FileAgreementName]),(0),charindex('.',reverse([FileAgreementName]))+(1))))),
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ASM_CONCLUSIONCARD_FILESSEA] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  Index [UI_ConclusionCardFile]    Script Date: 13.03.2022 22:07:57 ******/
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [UI_ConclusionCardFile] ON [dbo].[FilesSearch]
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  FullTextIndex     Script Date: 13.03.2022 22:07:57 ******/
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON [dbo].[FilesSearch](
[FileAgreementContent] TYPE COLUMN [FileExt] LANGUAGE 'Russian')
KEY INDEX [UI_ConclusionCardFile]ON ([FTConclusionFileSearch], FILEGROUP [PRIMARY])
WITH (CHANGE_TRACKING = AUTO, STOPLIST = SYSTEM)

CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG [FTConclusionFileSearch] WITH ACCENT_SENSITIVITY = ON 
AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
```

Comment: Is `pdf` in the list of Full Text filters in `select * from sys.fulltext_document_types`? Have you installed Adobe iFilter, see eg https://dba-presents.com/index.php/databases/sql-server/48-full-text-search-with-pdf-documents-in-sql-server-2014

Comment: Yes, C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe PDF iFilter 9 for 64-bit platforms\bin\PDFFilter.dll Version SQL Server: 2012

Comment: OK please show your table schema and full-text index, the `CREATE` statements

Comment: I added to the description

Comment: Looks like the `+ (1)` of `FileExt` should not be there https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=229d7221f348a85449396fde60ebf4d8, alternatively you can change the whole thing to `lower(substring(FileAgreementName, len(FileAgreementName) - charindex('.', reverse(FileAgreementName)) + 2, len(FileAgreementName)))`

Comment: Newly added pdfs have appeared in the list. But it does not search for old files

Comment: Rebuild the index `ALTER FULLTEXT CATALOG FTConclusionFileSearch REBUILD;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your `FileExt` column was a bit off, and was adding in the `.`. So remove the `+ 1` from it.

```sql
    [FileExt]  AS (lower(reverse(substring(reverse([FileAgreementName]),(0),charindex('.',reverse([FileAgreementName])))))),
```

Then rebuild the index

```sql
ALTER FULLTEXT CATALOG FTConclusionFileSearch REBUILD;
```